# Using JavaScript to call a Controller Function in an MVC project

Tags: javascript, c#, html, razor, model-view-controller

I'm working on an MVC ASP.NET core project with EF 6 which stores product data in a database and creates a processing and shipping list. An important feature of the project is for certain users to be able to change the order of this list manually, which I'm implementing using drag&drop cards. Each card is created by looping through an IEnumerable of the model in the View, with each

containing a partial which renders the card. The issue I'm having is that changing the order in the view doesn't inherently change the Product.Order attribute in the project. I need a way to access the model item of the card being moved and the model item.Order of the card being usurped inside the JavaScript drop function I have.

I'm currently trying with var order = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.Order) as String);, but that doesn't seem to be exposing anything to JavaScript that I can work with. I have a second line exposing the entire object.

Controller Method:

```cs
public void ChangeOrder(Product p, int order)
        {

            //This creates a list of all of the jobs in the database sorted by descending Order
            var PList = from prod in _context.Products select prod;
            PList = PList.OrderByDescending(prod => prod.Order);

            int origin = p.Order;
            p.Order = order;

            if(origin > order)
            {
                int it = order;
                while (it < origin && it < PList.Count())
                {
                    PList.ElementAt(it++).Order--;
                }
            } else if(origin < order)
            {
                int it = origin;
                while (it < order && it < PList.Count())
                {
                    PList.ElementAt(it++).Order--;
                }
            } else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```

Index View

```html
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Product>


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@*The list container*@
<ul class="container" id="dragfield" style="width: 100%;">
    @*The first card is a minicontainer for the create partial view*@
    <li class="card popupsrc" onclick="callPopup">...</li>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li class="dragcard" draggable="true" style="float: left; padding: 8px">@item.Order @*For debugging purposes, this displays the order with the card*@
            @*THE FOLLOWING LINEs ARE NOT SECURED AND SHOULD BE CHANGED BEFORE PUBLISHING - FOR TESTING PURPOSES ONLY*@
            var order = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.Order) as String);
            var order = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item) as String);
            <partial name="_ProductCard.cshtml" model="item" />
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

site.js Drag & Drop Block

```js
//D&D Functions Start
{
    var dragSrcElem = null;

    function dragStartHandler(event)
    {
        // Target (this) element is card being dragged.
        dragSrcElem = this;

        event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
        event.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.outerHTML);

        this.classList.add('dragElem');
    }
    function dragOverHandler(event)
    {
        if (event.preventDefault)
        {
            event.preventDefault(); //Enables dropping
        }
        this.classList.add('over');

        event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';

        return false;
    }

    function dragEnterHandler(event) {
        // this|event.target is the card being hovered over.
    }

    function dragLeaveHandler(event) {
        this.classList.remove('over');  // this|e.target is card previously hovered over.
    }

    function handleDrop(event) {
        // this/e.target is card about to be usurped.

        if (event.stopPropagation) {
            event.stopPropagation(); // Prevents browsers from redirecting and cancelling the drag&drop 
        }

        // If the card hasn't moved, do nothing
        if (dragSrcElem != this) {
            // Set the original card's HTML to the HTML of the card we dropped on
            this.parentNode.removeChild(dragSrcElem);
            var dropHTML = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
            this.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', dropHTML);
            //refocuses to the original card
            var dropElem = this.previousSibling;

//LOCATION OF ISSUE
            //call the Controller function to change the Order Attribute of the relocated card's item
            PFS.Controllers.ChangeOrder(dropElem, this.order);
//LOCATION OF ISSUE

            addDnDHandlers(dropElem);

        }
        this.classList.remove('over');
        return false;
    }

    function dragEndHandler(event) {
        // this|e.target is the original card.
        this.classList.remove('over');
    }

    function addDnDHandlers(elem) {
        elem.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStartHandler, false);
        elem.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnterHandler, false)
        elem.addEventListener('dragover', dragOverHandler, false);
        elem.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeaveHandler, false);
        elem.addEventListener('drop', dropHandler, false);
        elem.addEventListener('dragend', dragEndHandler, false);

    }

    var jc = document.querySelectorAll('#dragcard .dragcard');
    [].forEach.call(jc, addDnDHandlers);
}
//D&D Functions End
```

I expect the JavaScript handleDrop function to call a function in the controller using parameters from the view which originally called the JS function.
Currently the code I have implemented in the view does not expose the necessary information to the Javascript code in a way I know how to access, nor does JS recognize the Controller function

Answer (score 0):

From your JavaScript code, I'm not sure what exactly `PFS` is in the context of `PFS.Controllers.ChangeOrder...` so I'm not sure I could help there.

Personally, when I try to reach a controller action, I like to JavaScript's built-in `fetch` function. Essentially, you pass in the url as a parameter and an object if you want to specify any other details (like a body or something). It looks something like this:

```
//Of course you should replace this with your actual url, this one is just for demo //purposes.
const changeOrderUrl = "order/ChangeOrder"; 

fetch(changeOrderUrl, {
    method: "POST", //or GET or whatever your controller action is
    body: JSON.stringify({
        p: dropElem,
        order: this.order
    }),
    headers: { "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then((responseData) => {
    //Do whatever you want with the response here. IF you don't want to do anything with 
    //the response, you can remove both of the .then()'s
});
```

Additionally, you'll most likely have to add a `[FromBody]` attribute to the controller action's parameters like this:
`public void ChangeOrder([FromBody]Product p, int order)`

Let me know if I can assist in any other way!